# ORA-19602: cannot backup or copy active file in NOARCHIVELOG mode

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, database-backups

We are working with `Oracle 11g` database on Windows 8 and 10 OS environments. We need to dump (backup) database and then restore that dumped file into another oracle database, so we are trying **`Recovery Manager (RMAN)`** for it. We issues following commands :

> ```
> C:\Users\Admin>rman
> Recovery Manager: Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on Tue Mar 8 17:24:43 2016
> Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
> RMAN> connect target /
> connected to target database: MYEMP (DBID=42934358)
> RMAN> backup database;
>
> Starting backup at 08-MAR-16
> using target database control file instead of recovery catalog
> allocated channel: ORA_DISK_1
> channel ORA_DISK_1: SID=133 device type=DISK
> channel ORA_DISK_1: starting full datafile backup set
> channel ORA_DISK_1: specifying datafile(s) in backup set
> RMAN-03009: failure of backup command on ORA_DISK_1 channel at 03/08/2016 17:25:00
> ORA-19602: cannot backup or copy active file in NOARCHIVELOG mode
> continuing other job steps, job failed will not be re-run
> channel ORA_DISK_1: starting full datafile backup set
> channel ORA_DISK_1: specifying datafile(s) in backup set
> including current control file in backup set
> including current SPFILE in backup set
> channel ORA_DISK_1: starting piece 1 at 08-MAR-16
> RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
> RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
> RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
> RMAN-03009: failure of backup command on ORA_DISK_1 channel at 03/08/2016 17:25:02
> ORA-19504: failed to create file "C:\USERS\ADMIN\DESKTOPTEST\DATABASEBACKUP"
> ORA-27038: created file already exists
> OSD-04010: <create> option specified, file already exists
> ```

I have tried these to resolve the issue :

```
RMAN> run {
shutdown immediate;
startup mount;
backup database;
alter database open;
}
```

But nothing happen, we are getting error. How can I backup Oracle database using RMAN ? OR anything (script) that can help me to generate big database on my oracle server ?

Comment: you say you want to "dump" the database, do you mean you want to run and export data pump? in which case you don't need to use RMAN

Comment: I think you would have a better support on http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Are you actually still getting the ORA-19602 when the database is mounted but not open; or just the ORA-27038, which is pretty self-explanatory? And you do need to clarify your terminology as it isn't clear if you really want a backup/restore or an export/import.

Comment: @davegreen100 https://community.oracle.com/thread/2217844?start=0&tstart=0, it clearly state that RMAN is better option than data pump, so we want to go for RMAN.

Comment: @AlexPoole its backup/restore.

Answer (score 9):

I know that this is an older post, but i came across it today as i had the same issue, and found that the provided answers failed to provide a resolution for one thing that the original post attempted to do which is to set the state of the database to open once the backup completes.

According to Oracle

> To change the state of a target database that is in NOMOUNT or MOUNT state, you must either use SQL*Plus or use the RMAN SQL command to issue a SQL statement, as shown in these examples:

```
RMAN> SQL 'ALTER DATABASE OPEN';
```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/backup.102/b14192/setup002.htm

So you should be able to do something like

```
RMAN> run 
2> {
3> shutdown immediate
4> startup mount
5> backup database;
6> SQL 'ALTER DATABASE OPEN';
7>}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would like to say that as one of the error is like that

```
ORA-19602: cannot backup or copy active file in `NOARCHIVELOG` mode
```

Mostly this error comes when we shall to create a cold backup of the database running in noarchivelog mode using `RMAN`, the database should be mounted but not opened.  If the database is backed up in the open state, the following error will appear:

```
RMAN> backup database;
<....... output trimmed .......> 
<....... output trimmed .......> 
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== error message stack follows =============== 
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-03009: failure of backup command on ORA_DISK_1 channel at
08/03/2017 11:01:14
```

The following script shuts down the database and start it in mount mode, and then creates a backup of the database:

```
RMAN> run 
2> {
3> shutdown immediate
4> startup mount
5> backup database;
6> }
```

For your further ref [Here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_rman_28_noarchivelog_mode.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Please try issuing the RMAN commands separately rather than in a single run block. 
Thanks
Sabiha

Answer (score 0):

The command you're trying to utilize for backup seem to be correct, though the log messages state that a file already exists:

> RMAN-03009: failure of backup command on ORA_DISK_1 channel at
>   03/08/2016 17:25:02 ORA-19504: failed to create file
>   "C:\USERS\ADMIN\DESKTOPTEST\DATABASEBACKUP" ORA-27038: created file
>   already exists

In order to proceed, it should be fixed. Try to clean up the target backup directory, and try again, running the following command in rman:

```
run { 
    shutdown immediate;
    startup mount; 
    backup database; 
}
```

Once the backup process is finished you might want to startup the database.

Exit rman and establish a connection to your database via sqlplus, the command would look like the following one:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

and start it:

```
startup;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had shutdown using `shutdown abort` since this cause instance failure so we have to shutdown immediate and then mount the database.
I also tried to enable archiving but that failed too because the instance was failed due to the shutdown abort.

Answer (score 0):

What error code you get ?

in noarchivelog mode , you cannot take hot database backups, only cold.

When you activate archivelog mode ( in mount state), you can track old transaction during the backup time, and can forward the database to time in point recovery.